# R: How do I avoid getting an error when merging two data frames (group by/summarise)?

Tags: r, group-by, merge, summarize

I have a big `data frame` of 80,000 rows. It was created by combining individual `data frames` from different years. The `origin` variable indicates the year of the entry's original `data frame`.

Here is an example of the first few of the big `data frame` rows that show how data frames from 2003 and 2011 were combined.

```
df_1:
ID City State origin
1  NY   NY    2003 
2  NY   NY    2003
3  SF   CA    2003
1  NY   NY    2011
3  SF   CA    2011
2  NY   NY    2011
4  LA   CA    2011
5  SD   CA    2011
```

Now I want to create a new variable called `first_appearance` that takes the `min` of the `origin` variable for each `ID`:

```
final_df:
ID City State     origin   first_appearance
    1  NY   NY    2003     2003
    2  NY   NY    2003     2003
    3  SF   CA    2003     2003
    1  NY   NY    2011     2003
    3  SF   CA    2011     2003
    2  NY   NY    2011     2003
    4  LA   CA    2011     2011
    5  SD   CA    2011     2011
```

So far, I've tried using:

```
prestep_final <- df_1 %>% group_by(ID) %>% summarise(first_apperance = min(origin))
final_df <- merge(prestep_final, df_1, by = "ID")
```

`Prestep_final` works and produces a `data frame` with the `ID` and the `first_appearance`.

Unfortunately, the `merge` step doesn't work and yields a `data frame` with NA entries only.

How can I improve my code so that I can produce a table like `final_df` above. I'd appreciate any suggestions and don't have package preferences.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you change `summarise` to `mutate` you get your desired result without merging:

```r
library(tidyverse)

df <- tibble::tribble(
  ~ID, ~City, ~State, ~origin,
    1,  'NY',   'NY',    2003, 
    2,  'NY',   'NY',    2003,
    3,  'SF',   'CA',    2003,
    1,  'NY',   'NY',    2011,
    3,  'SF',   'CA',    2011,
    2,  'NY',   'NY',    2011,
    4,  'LA',   'CA',    2011,
    5,  'SD',   'CA',    2011
)

df %>% group_by(ID) %>% 
  mutate(first_appearance = min(origin))
#> # A tibble: 8 x 5
#> # Groups:   ID [5]
#>      ID City  State origin first_appearance
#>   <dbl> <chr> <chr>  <dbl>            <dbl>
#> 1     1 NY    NY      2003             2003
#> 2     2 NY    NY      2003             2003
#> 3     3 SF    CA      2003             2003
#> 4     1 NY    NY      2011             2003
#> 5     3 SF    CA      2011             2003
#> 6     2 NY    NY      2011             2003
#> 7     4 LA    CA      2011             2011
#> 8     5 SD    CA      2011             2011
```

<sup>Created on 2020-06-10 by the [reprex package](https://reprex.tidyverse.org) (v0.3.0)</sup>

Comment: Thank you, @MarBio!

Answer (score 1):

An option with `data.table`

```
library(data.table)
setDT(df)[, first_appearance := min(origin), ID]
```

---

Or in `base R`

```
df$first_appearance <- with(df, ave(origin, ID, FUN = min))
```

Comment: That's a really neat solution. Thank you @akrun!